# Парсинг формулы

Tags: c++builder, алгоритм, строки, c++

Нужно разбить входящую строку на подстроки для дальнейшего распознавания. Например `А1+В2+С3`.
Требуется разбить от и до +. То есть должно быть `А1,В2,С3`.
Код: 
Находим знаки и записываем в массив позиции где найдены даные символы

```
for(i = 0; i<=str.Length(); i++)
{    
  if (str[i]=='+' || str[i]=='-' ||
      str[i]=='*' || str[i]=='/'   )
  {
     pos[j] = i;  
     k = j;  
     j++;  
  }  
}
```

Далее разбиваем на подстроки

```
for (j = 0; j<=k; j++)  
  for (i = 0; i<=pos[j]; i++)
    a = a + str[i];
```

Все бы то, но выдает ошибку `RangeCheck Error`. В ходе проверки выяснилось, что не хочет принимать `str[1]` (1, 2, 3 не важно - ошибка при такой форме вычисления всегда). `str` типа `String` считывается с `Edit1`.

Comment: Возможно, вам будет интересна тема "[Арифметический парсер][1]", "[Считывание формулы откуда-либо и распознавание][2]" или темы с меткой "[регулярные выражения][3]"


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/12150
  [2]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/24200
  [3]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/tagged/%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
AnsiString str1;
str1 = str;
const char *c = str1.c_str(); //помогло
```

Answer (score 0):

Поменять в циклах "<=", на "<" ?

В str присутствуют данные или это пустая или null строка?

Comment: Дело не в "<=". В String str=Edit1=Text. Если брать str="asd", то все работает как надо.